# How to assign hotkeys to more than 4 worksapces in Gnome 40?

Tags: desktop-environment, gnome-shell

I am using Gnome 40 on Arch and I have hotkeys assigned for each of the 4 workspaces. But I'd like to set up hotkeys also for the 5th and the 6th workspace (e.g. super+5, super+6). How can I do that in GNOME 40?

There's this nice custom shortcuts section within the Keyboard settings but I don't know the actual command I'd have to enter in there. I guess it's the same command that helps me to switch the between the other 4 workspaces. [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the high-level schema-aware `gsettings` tool:

```
$ gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings | grep to-workspace 
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-workspace-5 @as []
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-5 @as []

$ for i in $(seq 9); do
      gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-workspace-$i "['<Shift><Super>$i']";
      gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-$i "['<Super>$i']";
  done
```

Unassign the shortcut from other actions, if any; for example:

```
$ gsettings list-recursively | grep Super | grep 3
org.gnome.shell.keybindings switch-to-application-3 ['<Super>3']

$ for i in $(seq 5); do gsettings set org.gnome.shell.keybindings switch-to-application-$i "[]"; done
```

Or you can use the low-level `dconf` tool, for example:

```
dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/wm/keybindings/switch-to-workspace-5 "['<Super>5']"
dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/wm/keybindings/move-to-workspace-5 "['<Super><Shift>5']"
```